# First email to potential PhD advisor

Tags: phd, advisor, application, quitting

I am currently doing a PhD in university X, but I am planning to quit, since I am looking for something more involved in my research interest.

Should I mention it in my first email to a potential phd advisor in university Y?

or is it sufficient to say that I am a research assistant at university X? 
and what about in the CV?

Comment: If you do, you may come across as fickle. If you don't, you may be perceived as dishonest. Of course, you probably realized that already, so your question is really "how can I spin my situation in my e-mail so it is not detrimental to my case"? And there's no way for us to answer the question based on the little bit of information provided. Stack Exchange is not really great for seeking personal advice in this manner.